wget unable to resolve localhost: "Failed to send 233 bytes (hostname='localhost', ip=::1, errno=111)"
I've moved from Mint to Fedora, and a script I have is no longer functioning:
wget -t 1 localhost:52199/MCWS/v1/Playback/PlayPause?Zone=-1&ZoneType=ID

returns
Failed to send 233 bytes (hostname='localhost', ip=::1, errno=111)

The issue is localhost. I can use wget to return from addresses that don't involve localhost such as www.google.com.
I can access the location in any browser.
I cannot access other localhost addresses I set up with SimpleHTTPServer.
I can get there by replacing "localhost" with my inet IP, but I'd like to resolve what the problem is as it seems like the sort of thing that will cause other issues.
127.0.0.1:52199/MCWS/v1/Playback/PlayPause?Zone=-1&ZoneType=ID

getent seems to return what it should:
name@fedora:~$ getent hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
name@fedora:~$ getent hosts foo.localhost
::1             localhost


Apart from Marcus' answer, if you read the wget manpage, you will see that you can force IPv4 connection with -4 or --inet4-only.

@Bob, thank you that does work. This not only gives me a solution but it seems that it isn't a problem that is going to have other impacts. It is strange that it worked differently in Mint, but that's the way it is with versions sometimes I guess. I shall mark Markus' answer as the solution.

Fedora seems to (correctly) resolve localhost to IPv6 ::1, before even trying IPv4.
My guess here is that your HTTP daemon isn't bound to an IPv6 address, and so doesn't get asked.

getent seems to return what it should:

but getent hosts isn't what is used to resolve names!
